# Which is faster to show active menu item? Switch + a bunch of echos OR a bunch of if statements?

Tags: php, if-statement, menu, switch-statement

Or is there an even better way?

Switch + a bunch of echos:

```
switch($currentpage) {
case 'index.php':
    $indexclass=' active';
    $otherpageclass='';
    break;
case 'otherpage.php':
    $indexclass='';
    $otherpageclass=' active';
    break;
}
```

Then, inside the li class I would simply echo out the $indexclass for index and $otherpageclass for other page.

The other option would be to just set the $currentpage variable and do something like:

```
<li class="<?php if($currentpage='index.php'){echo ' active';}?>">whatever</li>
<li class="<?php if($currentpage='otherpage.php'){echo ' active';}?>">whatever</li>
```

Obviously, my site is much larger than this and will probably have about 30 different menu items so I'm wondering which way is most efficient, or if there's an even better way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll probably need to have 10 million menu entries to notice a performance difference.

Comment: You could benchmark it yourself... but for 30 or so menu items I can't see you saving more than a few microseconds. Also, if all you are doing is trying to change the css class depending on the page you are on, you might want to do it with Javascript on the client-side

Comment: You've just spent more time writing this question than you would ever save in CPU cycles even if the site ran for a century.

Comment: Think about readability and forget performance, early optimizations is the root of all evils.

Comment: LOL @Sammitch - sorry for the dumb question. I'm still learning and every time I come back to code I've written 3 months, 6 months, 12 months ago I always find things I could have done much better - trying to minimize that and perhaps looking at things a tad bit too closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think speed should have nothing to do with this decision, as you are talking about micro-optimizations at best.

Do what is best for code readability and maintainability.  In my opinion, I would tend to lean more towards the approach where you are using the switch statement as, to me, this gives a cleaner separation between display logic and the actual display.

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose an even less performing solution: objects. I'd create a class so I'm able to define the menu this way:

```
$menu = new Menu($currentpage);
$menu->addItem('index.php', 'Home');
$menu->addItem('otherpage.php', 'Other Page');
echo $menu->html();
```

The exact code should not be difficult to figure out: an private array with items and a html() method to encapsulate the rendering.